# Display formula in cell (average function)

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data:

[image]

For each column, I want to calculate the average of the most current year. In the example below, I want to calculate it for 2020, so rows 164, 165 and 166. The result should appear in row 163.

However, I want not just the result, I want the formula so the user can see what is being calculated, but I can't. Maybe relevant: I'm using German Excel. I tried using `.FormulaLocal` and `MITTELWERT`(German for `AVERAGE`) but I think I'm making a different kind of mistake. With both `.Formula` and `.FormulaLocal` I'm getting a run time error 13 (type) in the line with the `.Formula`.

```
Sub FormulaLeased(ByVal fRow As Long, ByVal lCol As Long, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim i       As Long
    Dim iCol    As Long
    
   'manually setting values for this example:
    fRow = 164
    lCol = 7
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        Select Case Mid(.Cells(fRow, "A").Value, 4, 2) 'Determining the most recent quarter 
        Case "12"
            i = 3
        Case "09"
            i = 2
        Case "06"
            i = 1
        Case "03"
            i = 0
        End Select
        
        For iCol = 2 To lCol
            '---works, but only shows the result, not the forumla:                
            '.Cells(fRow - 1, iCol).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range(.Cells(fRow, iCol), .Cells(fRow + i, iCol))) 

            '---results in type error:
            .Cells(fRow - 1, iCol).Formula = "= Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(" & .Range(.Cells(fRow, iCol).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(fRow + i, iCol).Address(False, False)) & ")" 

        '---trying to use .FormulaLocal -> Type error
        '.Cells(fRow - 1, iCol).FormulaLocal = "= MITTELWERT(" & .Range(.Cells(fRow, iCol).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(fRow + i, iCol).Address(False, False)) & ")"
        Next iCol
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction` does not work with `.Formula` or `.FormulaLocal`. The `.Formula` needs the english formula as you would write it in the cell, and `.FormulaLocal` needs the localized formula (German) as you would write it in the cell.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried `.Cells(fRow - 1, iCol).Formula = "= AVERAGE(" & .Range(.Cells(fRow, iCol).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(fRow + i, iCol).Address(False, False)) & ")"`, still getting the same error. Same with the `MITTELWERT` I already tried in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.WorksheetFunction` does not work with `.Formula` or `.FormulaLocal`. The `.Formula` needs the English formula as you would write it in the cell, and `.FormulaLocal` needs the localized formula (German) as you would write it in the cell.

So this approach was the one to go:

```
.Cells(fRow - 1, iCol).FormulaLocal = "= MITTELWERT(" & .Range(.Cells(fRow, iCol).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(fRow + i, iCol).Address(False, False)) & ")"
```

but needs to be changed to

```
.Cells(fRow - 1, iCol).FormulaLocal = "=MITTELWERT(" & .Cells(fRow, iCol).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(fRow + i, iCol).Address(False, False) & ")"
```

there is no `Range` needed just the addresses of the 2 cells.

Note that this code will only work if you run it in a German Excel because `MITTELWERT` will not be translated to other localizations. If you plan that your code should run on a French Excel too, then you would need to use the English formula and `.Formula`. This will translate to any localization and therefore work in **all** Excel versions. I highly recommend to use `.Formula` and translate them yourself into English (https://excel-translator.de might help):

```
.Cells(fRow - 1, iCol).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & .Cells(fRow, iCol).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(fRow + i, iCol).Address(False, False) & ")"
```